# Generate module with component and routing in Angular 8 (using angular cli command)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I have created new angular project using angular cli command **ng new my-app**

Then, I wanted to create module named **landing-page** inside `src/app` directory, so i used command **ng g m landing-page --routing=true** which creates two files i.e. one module and one its routing file as following :

```
src/app/landing-page/landing-page-routing.module.ts (254 bytes) 

src/app/landing-page/landing-page.module.ts (300 bytes)
```

but Now, instead of that i want to create module with its root component and routing both in single folder named as landing-page, so how can i do that with single cli command ?

Comment: The only existing solution is to create your own schematic command(https://angular.io/guide/schematics-authoring).

Comment: hmm ok, i am not aware of this and was expecting that there might be command to do so as asked in question

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no way to do this as of yet in one single command other than creating your own schematic command as mentioned in the comments because the `module` and `component` are two different schematics and as per the [documentation](https://angular.io/cli/generate), the `<schematic>` argument in `ng g <schematic> [options]` can only take one sub-command.

You can, however, combine two commands in one line using `&&` and create a module and the component in the same folder.

```
ng g m landing-page --routing=true && ng g c landing-page --skip-tests=true -m=landing-page
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `--module app.module` which helps to update in `app.module`.

Below command creates a home module, a component with a routing module.

```sh
ng g m home --routing=true --module app.module && ng g c home
```

I would like to suggest you use lazy loading routing which helps in a big application for route lazy loading and app performance.

User below command to create a `module`, `component`, `route` and it will also update your `app-routing.module.ts`.

```
ng g m home --route home --module app.module
```

Answer (score 4):

ng g m Header --route header --module app.module

this command create , parent module , parent component , and routing , try it .. tc

Answer (score 1):

This command create module, component and routes in angular

[image: 1]

ng g m admin --routing=true --module app.module && ng g c admin